# How do I hide the editor margin that displays the "lightbulb" icon in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am talking about this:

[image]

Takes too much space and is a bit annoying. Is there any way to hide the margin and the icon?

Comment: What happens if you press `Ctrl`+`.` at that line? That's the keyboard shortcut for Quick Actions (the light bulb feature). I'm not at my home machine at the moment so I can't test things.

Comment: I've played around with it a bit and it doesn't seem like there's any setting or option to turn it off. Quick Actions is a new feature in VS2015. Perhaps you can send Microsoft feedback or a frown and let them know that people don't want this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MussiKara.HideSuggestionAndOutliningMargins) that hides the suggestion margin, but it also hides the outline margin, which might be undesirable for you. The source code is only a few lines as shown in the screenshot, simply removing the outlining line will do the trick.